# Share child account data with parent account users in experience

Tags: experience-cloud, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing

We have a requirement to share child account data ( Contact, ChildObject1__c and ChildObject2__c) with parent account users. We tried sharing the records by using Account Relationships and it works well if both the accounts are portal accounts. However, customers are now saying they need the records to be shared even if the child account is not a portal account.

Sharing set is already used to share records among the users under same account. So, that is not an option too.

Is there any way to achieve this without APEX sharing? The sharing has to trigger

- whenever an account is made parent of another account.
- whenever a new user is added to parent account.

We have high volume users in communities so dynamically creating a group with parent company, and all child companies and managing records via apex may not be a good option too.

Comment: For anyone wondering what happened with this requirement, I had to implement APEX-based sharing. It was a bit of work but is working as expected. I will keep the question open if anyone else has a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to implement sharing between community user parent account and child accounts.  I need my parent account contacts to see and edit the records of the child accounts. I see you were able to accomplish this using Account Relationships.  Can you elaborate more on how you accomplished this or provide a link?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You can contribute in other ways to earn enough rep so that you can comment on this question; or you could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question for reference.

Comment: Hello @AUEagle2005, sorry to disappoint you but for account relationships to work, both accounts need to be portal accounts. I had to implement APEX sharing to accomplish what I needed.